# How to align three items in same row with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to align three items in the same row but am having problems doing this in Bootstrap 3. Here is how they look now:

[image]

But I want them to be aligned in the same row (horizontally) and not be aligned vertically.

I have a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2132/

The relevant code is:

```
 <div class="pull-right">
        <form action="#" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-label">
                <div class="control">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull right on a form will only work if the form has a specific width. In most cases you don't want to use that, but use the grid system.

You should use [`.input-group`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) to add buttons to an input and show them on the same line.

You're not using labels, so there is no use for `.form-horizontal`.

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/618bbk7z/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Pill1</a>
            </li>
            <li class=""><a href="#"><span id="pendingcount">Pill2</span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="Date" name="filtertype" class="dropdown-field">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Date <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="date">Date</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="requestor">Requestor</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="classification">Classification</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="destination">Destination</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="description">Description</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="filename">File Name</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="extractedtext">Extracted Text</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="extractedkeyword">Extracted Keywords</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="status">Status</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="#" data-value="scancode">Scan Code</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="filterterm" value="" class="form-control">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default "> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```